# strange behaviour of filehandle.tell() function

Tags: python

I don't get why the tell() function doesn't work in this case. Let's create a file with the string "1\n2\n3\n4\n" inside:

```
f=open('test.tmp','w')
f.write('1\n2\n3\n4\n')
f.close()
```

Now, let's open it and run the following code:

```
fTellResults=[]
f=open('test.tmp','r+')
for line in f:
    fTellResults.append(f.tell())
f.close()
print fTellResults
```

As a result I get:

```
[8L, 8L, 8L, 8L]
```

However, I would expect rather this:

```
[2L, 4L, 6L, 8L]
```

Could anyone explain me why it works like this and how could I get the expected result?

p.s. I use Python 2.7.1 on Linux

Comment: Amusingly, CPython seems to be kind of an outlier here: both PyPy 1.7 and ironpython 2.6 Beta 2 on linux return [2L, 4L, 6L, 8L].  But for the reasons quoted by Felix Loether, it's clear that returning the expected result isn't implicitly guaranteed as part of the language spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### [file.next()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next)
>
> A file object is its own iterator, for example `iter(f)` returns *f* (unless *f* is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a `for` loop (for example, `for line in f: print line`), the `next()` method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises `StopIteration` when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing). In order to make a `for` loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right. However, using `seek()` to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

Based on this I claim the position given by `file.tell` is incorrect because the file was already read to the read-ahead buffer.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to access this hidden read-ahead buffer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `for line in f:` causes all lines to be read before executing the loop.  So then in each iteration of the loop, `tell()` just stays constant at the end of the file.  For the desired behavior, you need to do readline inside the loop